# gcc and g++ in Mac

Tags: linux, mac, bash, macbook, gcc

I bought a new Macbook Pro.  Like linux, it has a bash shell.  However, I did not find gcc or g++ in there.  Is it in there somewhere, or is there some kind of package manager that will allow me to easily add it in?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to install the XCode tools from [here](http://developer.apple.com/technology/xcode.html).

Comment: You shouldn't need to download XCode - it should be on your install disk under Optional Installs.

Answer (score 1):

In XCode, go to the XCode menu, followed by Preferences, Downloads, and then click on the Install button.